# Create a statistics nested dictionary from a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nested

I have a list of many nested dictionaries, each dictionary represent a Windows OS and looks like this:

```
windows1 = {"version": "windows 10", 
            "installed apps": {"chrome": "installed",
                               "python": {"python version": "2.7", 
                                          "folder": "c:\python27"},
                               "minecraft": "not installed"}}

windows2 = {"version": "windows XP", 
            "installed apps": {"chrome": "not installed",
                               "python": {"python version": "not installed", 
                                          "folder": "c:\python27"},
                               "minecraft": "not installed"}}
```

My goal is to create a final nested dictionary, to store statistics about the list, that will look like this:

```
stats_dic = {"version": {"windows 10": 20,
                         "windows 7": 4, 
                         "windows XP": 11},
             "installed apps": {"chrome": {"installed": 12, 
                                           "not installed": 6},
                                "python": {"python version": {"2.7": 4, "3.6": 8, "3.7": 2}, 
                                "minecraft": {"installed": 15, 
                                              "not installed": 2}}}
```

As you can see, im trying to take all the values in each windows dict in the list (except the python folder), making them as keys in the final nested statistics dict. The value for these keys will be a counter of them and they have to stay in the same nested way as before.

After some reading i understand that this can be done in a recursive function, and i have tried several functions with no luck. The closest i got (without taking care of the python folder) is:

```
stats_dic = {}
windows_list = [s1, s2.....]

def update_recursive(s,d):
    for k, v in s.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            update_recursive(v, d)
        else:
            if v in d.keys():
                d[v] += 1
            else:
                d.update({v: 1})
    return d

for window in windows_list():
    stats_dic = update_recursive(window, stats_dic)
```

Which gave me for windows1 and windows2:

```
{'windows XP': 1, 'windows 10': 1, '2.7': 1, 'not installed': 2, 'c:\\python27': 1, 'installed': 1}
```

As you can see, it doesnt keep its nested form and also, mixes same values (the chrome and mincraft 'not installed')
Everything else ive tried either did not increase the counter or kept the nested form for only a depth of one. I know Im not close, but what am I missing?

Comment: you never do anything with `k`. you need to add nested dicts with your `k`s to `stats_dic` as you recurse in order to get anything approaching the output you want.

Comment: @acushner hi, do you mean ```d[k] = update_recursive(v, d)``` at the first if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive function that will do what I think you want it to do.

```
from pprint import pp # Skip if you're not running Python >= 3.8
def combiner(inp, d=None):
    if d == None:
        d = {}
    for key, value in inp.items():
        if isinstance(value, str):
            x = d.setdefault(key, {})
            x.setdefault(value, 0)
            x[value] += 1
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            x = d.setdefault(key, {})
            combiner(value, x)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Unexpected type '{}' for 'value'".format(type(value)))
    return d

windows1 = {"version": "windows 10", 
            "installed apps": {"chrome": "installed",
                               "python": {"python version": "2.7", 
                                          "folder": "c:\python27"},
                               "minecraft": "not installed"}}
windows2 = {"version": "windows XP", 
            "installed apps": {"chrome": "not installed",
                               "python": {"python version": "not installed", 
                                          "folder": "c:\python27"},
                               "minecraft": "not installed"}}
windowsList = [windows1, windows2]

x = {}
for comp in windowsList:
    combiner(comp, x)
pp(x) # Use print if you're not running Python >= 3.8
```

Output:

```
{'version': {'windows 10': 1, 'windows XP': 1},
 'installed apps': {'chrome': {'installed': 1, 'not installed': 1},
                    'python': {'python version': {'2.7': 1, 'not installed': 1},
                               'folder': {'c:\\python27': 2}},
                    'minecraft': {'not installed': 2}}}
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed, thank you so much. Learn about d.setdefault and pp aswell, awsome!

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution to your request.

The answer is structured in three parts:

1. Flatten input dictionaries
2. Create table (pandas DataFrame)
3. Calculate statistics and structure the output

(To see the whole code without explanatory steps, scroll to the very bottom.)

#### Explanation

What do I mean by flatten the input dictionaries? The answer is straightforward: a dictionary that is ***not*** nested and therefore just has key, value pairs that are one dimensional.

```
# Flat dictionary vs. nested dictionary
flat = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
nested = {'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}} # 'b' has another dictionary as value
```

1.

```
# Flatten input dictionaries

# Following function returns a 1 dimensional dictionary where
# the before nested structure is still recognizable in its keys
# in the form parent.child.subchild...

def flatten(dic):
    #
    update = False
    
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            update = True
            break
    
    if update:
        val_key_tree = dict([(f'{key}.{k}', v) for k,v in val.items()])
        dic.update(val_key_tree); dic.pop(key); flatten(dic)
    
    return dic

# Example
windows1 = {"version": "windows 10", 
            "installed apps": {"chrome": "installed",
                               "python": {"python version": "2.7", 
                                          "folder": "c:\python27"},
                               "minecraft": "not installed"}}

flatten(windows1)
>>> {'version': 'windows 10',
     'installed apps.chrome': 'installed',
     'installed apps.minecraft': 'not installed',
     'installed apps.python.python version': '2.7',
     'installed apps.python.folder': 'c:\\python27'}
```

Having a reference of the nested structure in the keys will come in handy later on when recreating the structure of the original dictionaries.

2.

```
# Create table (pandas DataFrame)
# With one dimensional dictionaries, it easy to create a pandas DataFrame where each row represents a dictionary

import pandas as pd

# Input
windows1 = {"version": "windows 10", 
            "installed apps": {"chrome": "installed",
                               "python": {"python version": "2.7", 
                                          "folder": "c:\python27"},
                               "minecraft": "not installed"}}

windows2 = {"version": "windows XP", 
            "installed apps": {"chrome": "not installed",
                               "python": {"python version": "not installed", 
                                          "folder": "c:\python27"},
                               "minecraft": "not installed"}}

dics = [windows1, windows2]

# Create DataFrame
frames = [pd.DataFrame(flatten(dic), index=[0]) for dic in dics]
df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
df
>>>
```

[image]

3.

```
# Statistics
# Thanks to the DataFrame it is relatively simple to count how many times a value appears within a column

for c in df.columns: # iterate over dataframe columns
    #
    if 'folder' in c: # exclude certain columns (for example when 'folder' appears in column)
        continue

    uniques = df[c].unique() # all different values from a column

    # Count how many times a value appears per column
    counts = {}
    for u in uniques:
        tmp_u = u if not '\\' in u else u.replace('\\','\\\\') # backlash needs to be escaped specially
        counts[u] = int(df[c].str.count('^'+tmp_u).sum())      # with the following str-method from dataframe
    
    print(counts) # output from variable counts for each iteration
>>> {'windows 10': 1, 'windows XP': 1}
    {'installed': 1, 'not installed': 1}
    {'not installed': 2}
    {'2.7': 1, 'not installed': 1}
```

From here on, we can recreate the structure of the original dictionaries because we have these references in the DataFrame columns.
Following function will create a nested dictionary structured like the original dictionaries with the statistics calculated above:

```
# Recreate structured dictionary
def build_nested(struct, tree, res):
    #
    tree_split = tree.split('.',1)
    
    try:
        struct[tree_split[0]]
        build_nested(struct[tree_split[0]], tree_split[-1], res)
    except KeyError:
        struct[tree_split[0]] = {}
        if len(tree_split) < 2:
            struct[tree_split[0]].update(res)
        else:
            struct[tree_split[0]][tree_split[1]] = {}
            struct[tree_split[0]][tree_split[1]].update(res)
    
    return struct
```

So instead of printing during each iteration like in the 3rd section above, we can pass the found attributes to the above function build_nested like this:

```
# Statistics
stats = {}

for c in df.columns:
    #
    if 'folder' in c:
        continue
    
    uniques = df[c].unique()
    
    # Count how many times a value appears per column
    counts = {}
    for u in uniques:
        tmp_u = u if not '\\' in u else u.replace('\\','\\\\')
        counts[u] = int(df[c].str.count('^'+tmp_u).sum())
    
    # Recreate the structure of nested dictionary
    build_nested(stats, c, counts)

stats
>>>{'version': {'windows 10': 1, 'windows XP': 1},
    'installed apps': {'chrome': {'installed': 1, 'not installed': 1},
    'minecraft': {'not installed': 2},
    'python': {'python version': {'2.7': 1, 'not installed': 1}}}}
```

#### Whole code

```
# Whole process put together
import json
import pandas as pd

# Helper functions
def flatten(dic):
    #
    update = False
    
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            update = True
            break
    
    if update:
        val_key_tree = dict([(f'{key}.{k}', v) for k,v in val.items()])
        dic.update(val_key_tree); dic.pop(key); flatten(dic)
    
    return dic

def build_nested(struct, tree, res):
    #
    tree_split = tree.split('.',1)
    
    try:
        struct[tree_split[0]]
        build_nested(struct[tree_split[0]], tree_split[-1], res)
    except KeyError:
        struct[tree_split[0]] = {}
        if len(tree_split) < 2:
            struct[tree_split[0]].update(res)
        else:
            struct[tree_split[0]][tree_split[1]] = {}
            struct[tree_split[0]][tree_split[1]].update(res)
    
    return struct

# 1. & 2. Flatten input dictionaries and create table (pandas DataFrame)
windows1 = {"version": "windows 10", 
            "installed apps": {"chrome": "installed",
                               "python": {"python version": "2.7", 
                                          "folder": "c:\python27"},
                               "minecraft": "not installed"}}

windows2 = {"version": "windows XP", 
            "installed apps": {"chrome": "not installed",
                               "python": {"python version": "not installed", 
                                          "folder": "c:\python27"},
                               "minecraft": "not installed"}}

dics = [windows1, windows2]

frames = [pd.DataFrame(flatten(dic), index=[0]) for dic in dics]
df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)

# 3. Recreate nested dictionary with statistics    
stats = {}
for c in df.columns:
    #
    if 'folder' in c:
        continue
    
    uniques = df[c].unique()
    
    # Count how many times a value appears per column
    counts = {}
    for u in uniques:
        tmp_u = u if not '\\' in u else u.replace('\\','\\\\')
        counts[u] = int(df[c].str.count('^'+tmp_u).sum())
    
    # Recreate the structure of nested dictionary
    build_nested(stats, c, counts)

print(json.dumps(stats, indent=5))
>>>
{
     "version": {
          "windows 10": 1,
          "windows XP": 1
     },
     "installed apps": {
          "chrome": {
               "installed": 1,
               "not installed": 1
          },
          "minecraft": {
               "not installed": 2
          },
          "python": {
               "python version": {
                    "2.7": 1,
                    "not installed": 1
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Learned many new things just from reading this, its a very smart way for approaching the problem thats going to help me in the future. Thank you for the detailed answer, Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to hear it was of help. Thanks for the feedback.